# Sql Server In statement with Null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have the following:

```
select Firstname, LastName, Department
from Employee
where 
     Department is null
  or Department in (
       select Department
       from Employee
       group by Department
       having COUNT(1) < 5)
```

This takes a /long/ time (over 10 minutes) and I'm assuming it's eventually time out.

I can change it to:

```
select Firstname, LastName, Department
from Employee
where 
  coalesce(Department,'') in (
       select coalesce(Department,'')
       from Employee
       group by Department
       having COUNT(1) < 5)
```

which, in this case, gives me what I need.  It returns in 2 seconds.

If I just doing the first query with either part of the where clause returns quick.  I also unioned them and it return quickly as well.  Any insight on why it's freaking out when i combine them?

Comment: Please post the execution plans. You could also do `SELECT Firstname, LastName, Department FROM (select *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Department) AS Cnt from Employee) T WHERE Cnt < 5` BTW.

Comment: The Employee object is a view... so.. it's big...

Comment: He asked for the execution plans, not the code behind the view.

Comment: Because of the code behind the view, the execution plan is huge.. there are tons of joins in that view

Comment: If i export the execution plan to xml it's 2690 lines long.  I'll post it, but I don't think it's all that relavent

Comment: @Rob: It's not strange that UNION ALL solution is faster because: `COALESCE(Column, ) IN ()` isn't SARG-able and `Column IS NULL` &  `Column IN ()` are [SARG-able](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/more-small-code-changes-bigger-sql-server-performance-improvements). There are a limited number of cases where/when a function/expression applied on a column allows an Index Seek ( `CAST/CONVERT(DATE, DateTimeColumn), computed columns)`. In this case COALESCE blocks an Index Seek on Departament column.

Comment: The coalesce and the Union (or union all) perform about the same.  it's the first query which performs poorly.